# Should I always maintain the inner exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code and I'm trying to provide more information for the exception:

```
int id = 5;
try
{
    var record = db.MyTable
                   .Where(x.Id == 5)
                   .Single();
    // more code here ...
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    string message = string.Format("Record doesn't exists for Id {0}", id);
    throw new InvalidOperationException(message, ex);
}
```

Should I maintain the inner exception even when this exception doesn't provide more relevant information other than the stacktrace? like the code above or;

Should I ignore the exception and just throw what I need? like this `throw new InvalidOperationException(message);`

Comment: Why are you relying on exceptions to drive your logic? Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Single()` and examine the result. Then if you have no items back, you can throw an exception.

Comment: If you don't care about the exception, then don't include it as an error. That's a decision for you to make. Then again, what's the harm in doing it? Maybe you'll need it later.

Comment: @vcsjones, the result would be whatever is contained in `MyTable`, presumably *not* an integer but instead a data entity. Of course, the asker is the only one in a position to know for sure.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Oh you're right, I misread the code. I somehow got the idea that the sequence was ints.

Comment: That is exactly my point. The exception should provide enough information to the caller so he/she can fix the issue. But I'm not sure if providing information like the inner exception is really providing any value to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you have asked depends on the operation executing. If I were you I will always keep the Inner exception as much as possible. From the above example you may not need the Inner exception.

But let us take this scenario

```
public class EmployeeDAO
{
    public void EmployeeInsert(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {
           //Insert a Employee
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = string.Format("Record doesn't exists for Id {0}", id);
            throw new Exception(message, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above if you catch and rethrow the as shown, you will loose the inner exception. The inner exception will have useful information like Connection Issue or Command Time Out or any thing of that sort.

Comment: Note that information provided by exception is useful for other "consumers" as well - any internal details makes hacking programs/sites easier, so more information you expose more people will thank you for that (even if most are not so legitimate users).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. Yes the let us take you want to exposing a WCF service in that case you will have handle the exception and return graceful messages. Where in the exception information should not be returned. Even then the exception should be logged properly for Developer purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use of pre-existing exception types for things like the above can be ugly, because there's no general way to distinguish an `InvalidOperationException` which `Single` throws because the number of matching records wasn't exactly one, from an `InvalidOperationException` which gets thrown for some entirely different reason.  If `InvalidOperationException` gets thrown for some unexpected reason and you simply report the exception as though the reason was expected, troubleshooting may be difficult.  On the other hand, if you do keep the exception it's not exactly clear what a client is going to do with it.

Perhaps, even though making decisions based on exception messages is generally ugly, there might be some benefit to examining the message associated with the underlying exception and stifling the inclusion of the inner exception in cases where the message matches expectations.  Such usage could make the code somewhat brittle with regard to changes in the `Single` method, but would offer better behavior both in the cases where the single method throws an exception with an expected message, and also in the cases where where something throws an `InvalidOperationException` for unexpected reasons.  Those two "wins" might be sufficient to overcome the fact that changes to `Single` might cause the code to start needlessly including inner exceptions in what should be regarded as expected scenarios.